# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) ....... following the upgrade of react-native version

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux, react-intl

I am getting the following error when i open my app from android phone.
the code used to work fine on react-native version 0.55.3. but since i made upgrade, it started giving me the error.
[image: Error screenshot]

react-native version 0.63.3

I have index.tsx in my root directory as follows:

```
  import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
  import App from './src/App';
   
  AppRegistry.registerComponent('awesomeapp', () => App);
```

and my app.tsx as follows:

```
import Intl from 'intl';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {ActivityIndicator, Text, YellowBox} from 'react-native';
import {ThemeProvider} from 'react-native-material-ui';
import {IntlProvider} from 'react-intl';
import {uiTheme} from './styles';
import store, {persistor} from './store';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

import Root from './components/Root';
import {configureLocaleData, getLocale, getMessagesByLocale} from "./i18n/i18n";

(window as any).Intl = Intl;   
 class App extends React.Component<any> {
    
        renderLoading = () => (
            <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
        );
    
        render() {
            const locale: string = getLocale();
            configureLocaleData(locale);
            console.log("Locale is " + locale);
            const message = getMessagesByLocale(locale);
    
            return (
                <IntlProvider locale={locale} textComponent={Text} messages={message}>
                    <ThemeProvider uiTheme={uiTheme}>
                        <Provider store={store}>
                            <PersistGate persistor={persistor} loading={this.renderLoading()}>
                                <Root/>
                            </PersistGate>
                        </Provider>
                    </ThemeProvider>
                </IntlProvider>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default App;
```

any help regarding this error is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?